# Identify and possibly translate a sentence from a language similar to thai

Tags: translation, language-identification, khmer

I apologize for the unconventionality of the question, I'm trying to identifying the language in the sample, and possibly obtain a translation of what's written. I figured if there's a community in which I can find help it is Stackexchange.

Note that a priori I'm not sure that the sample doesn't need rotating by 180°, however, I think this is the correct orientation because of the last character of the first word, which reminds me of an "a" vowel in thai.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit questions about translation are offtopic on this site, here's the way how to identify the language by yourself.

First, note that **it is Khmer**. *In the future, you should always provide with some information where the scan came from.* This will help you limit your search.

The image is rotated upside-down. Here's the correct orientation:

[image]

The first line reads something like:

> ខំុពេញចិកូនេះដៃទៃន។

**Note:** I'm not familiar with Khmer, so mistakes are very possible.

To type the entire text, you may experiment with [online Khmer keyboard](http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/khmer.htm) plus some online translator (like Google or Bing) to get a meaningful result.

You may also refer some basic reference for Khmer [consonants](http://www.bongthom.com/akonline/consonants.asp) and [vovels](http://www.bongthom.com/akonline/vowels.asp) to know how to read it.

Note, your browser may not show the fonts properly (or, let me say, the most nice ones). It depends on the fonts used to display StackExchange. See how it looks in my browser (above) versus the [Lexilogos Web site](http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/khmer.htm) (below).

[image]